# What magic items are there that help a Sorcerer summon or control undead?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, undead, sorcerer, necromancy

I am trying to compile the short list of items that a Sorcerer can use to summon / control undead.  Which magic items support this Sorcerer concept?

The character is currently a Divine Sorcerer, level 7.

The magic items need to be able to summon undead and / or buff undead.  *Buffing* in this case means making them stronger or adding to their utility in some way.

I am using the [*animate dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) spell.  I do plan to get [*create undead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-undead) also.

Comment: You are really going to have to narrow this down here. Who is trying to perform necromancy (what are their abilities)? What is the goal they are trying to accomplish with necromancy? PC or NPC? Story or combat/mechanics? Really the key thing is that you need to define a goal here besides just "related to necromancy" since that is very much undefined.

Comment: What Rubiksmoose said. If you ask something like, "What magic items would help me accomplish [goal X] using necromancy?" we might be able to answer that... but as it stands, this is an idea-generation question without even a clear goal. To be suitable for the RPG.SE/StackExchange format, there needs to be a way to determine a "best" answer, even for [subjective questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). Right now, there's no way to provide such an answer to this question. If you tell us why you're asking the question, we can help you reformulate it.

Comment: I have expanded the question, I hope that works.

Comment: Relevant metas: [What are list questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/what-are-list-questions), [Are list/collection questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/are-list-collection-questions-on-topic) ...In general, "idea generation" questions are generally not suited to the Stack Exchange format because there's no way to choose a "best answer"; the answers simply devolve into a potentially unending list of ideas.

Comment: Also: How is a sorcerer summoning undead? The only relevant necromancy spell that they seem to have is [Finger of Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death), a 7th-level spell that raises the target as a zombie if killed by the damage (and humanoid). Even assuming they can summon undead, I don't see the connection between that their other spells like Fireball and Blight. And asking for a totally separate list of items ("Items that also expand the ability to use more spells than normal.") is making an already broad question even more broad.

Comment: Divine Sorc has access to Cleric Spells. It's legal to take animate long has you spec into that bloodline far has I know

Comment: @SeigSoloyvov: Ah, true, I hadn't accounted for that. You may want to clarify that in the question, then.

Comment: What level is your Sorcerer (i.e. is he/she using *raise dead*, *create undead*, or some other spell?) To be honest, with the qualifiers you've given the list is going to be too broad. "benefit the summoning" and "make the... summon better in some way" includes almost every magic item since undead can attuned to magic items. I would choose one narrow qualifier for this question. You are always welcome to ask more questions such as a separate one for the ability to use more spells than normal.

Comment: There I pretty limited the question to two things.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I think it's still too broad; "+3 weapons and armor for every(un)body!" is "making them stronger". If you explicitly restrict magic items to those used by the caster, it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

### Enhancing Yourself

As a necromancer, it's very important to not just have undead, but to have control of those undead. Quality over quantity. Thus, it's helpful to ensure you can maximize your daily castings of Animate Dead. As a 3rd level spell, it's relatively easy to recover castings of the spell; conversely Create Undead is a 6th level spell and thus much more difficult to gain more castings on, I could not locate any practical magic items that would permit you to reliably get multiple daily castings of Create Undead.

- Ring of Spell Storing is a good way to give yourself an extra daily casting of Animate Dead. As a Sorcerer, there's a good chance that you'll have a means to ensure you've an extra 3rd level slot daily that you can pour into it to power that spell.
- Reserve Ioun Stone is another good way to get in an additional Animate Dead in daily.
- Pearl of Power is the last way I've identified to regain another spell slot and with it another casting of Animate Dead.

### Enhancing Undead

As for the undead themselves, the list of ways to enhance them is far too numerous to detail here as any armor, weapon, etc. you can find you could slap on them and have them be 'buffed'. That said, the disposable nature of undead does open up the possibility of spending that Bonus Action in a more interesting manner other than 'mercilessly kill all my hated enemies'.

- Shove a Portable Hole into a Bag of Holding right next to my hated enemies.
- Break a fully charged Staff of Power/Staff of the Magi right next to my hated enemies.
- Get next to my hated enemies and throw Dust of Sneezing and Choking into the air.
- Spray this Decanter of Endless Water at my hated enemies.
- Wear this belt of Storm Giant Strength, smear  yourself in Sovereign Glue, and grapple my hated enemies.

Comment: Can undead wear armor?  I thought they just got the stat block from the MM.

Answer (score -3):

If you kill any humanoid with the spell [*finger of death*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death), it will raise as a permanent servant of you. So if you kill a giant this way, you should have a permanent giant undead. You have to talk with your DM about this last one, but if you kill a level 11 fighter this way, you should have a permanent level 11 fighter as a minion. There is nothing in the spell text indicating that the minion loses any abilities by becoming undead.

Comment: Two problems. First of all, giants can't be raised as undead by [*finger of death*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/finger-of-death); giant is a type, different from humanoid. Secondly, there is something in the spell text that tells you exactly what stats the resulting creature has; it tells you that a humanoid killed by the spell rises as a "zombie", which refers to the [zombie](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/zombie) statblock.